# Can I append a parent and child at the same time using event targeting?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to use event targeting to create an unordered list with list items containing the values of different clicked checkboxes.

```
$(this).click(function(e) {
    var myElem = document.getElementById(e.target.name);
    var price = parseInt(e.target.value);

    if (myElem == null){
        $('.container').append('<ul id="'+e.target.name+'">'+e.target.name+'</ul>');
    }
    if ($(this).name = myElem){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')){     
            sum += price;
            $('#'+e.target.name+'').append('<li>Cost: $'+sum+'</li>');
        } else {
            sum -= price;
            $('#'+e.target.name+' li').last().remove();
        }
    }
```

It works except for the first list item. I think this is because the first list item has nowhere to go because the unordered list is being made at the same time. Is there a way to create both at once or delay the list item creation until after the unordered list is made?

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dfzrt3qt/2/

Comment: you forgot one close tag `</ul>` line 7.

Comment: Ah thanks good catch

Comment: `if( something === something)` you can not just have one `=` for if. you need at least 2 better are 3 equal signs. one equal sign is assigning a value.  talking about this `if ($(this).name = myElem){`

Comment: @caramba even if that's fixed, it's still trying to compare a non-existent `.name` property to an element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are bunch of issues with the current implementation.

The click event is triggered by checkbox. You are trying to target the element where id = e.target.name , which is "productname". No such element exists.

```
var myElem = document.getElementById(e.target.name);
```

The reason why the 1st click doesn't show the amount is because you are targeting 'ul' tag which doesn't have a value attribute.

```
 $('.container').append('<ul id="'+e.target.name+'">'+e.target.name+'<ul>');
 var price = parseInt(e.target.value);
  $('#'+e.target.name+'').append('<li>Cost: $'+sum+'</li>');
```

HERE'S HOW TO FIX IT : ( UPDATED )

```
$('.days').find(':checkbox').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(e) {    
            var sum = 0;
            var price = parseInt(e.target.value);
            if ($('ul[id="' + e.target.name + '"]')[0] == undefined){
                $('.container').append('<ul id="' + e.target.name + '">'+e.target.name+'</ul>');
             }

            sum += parseInt($('#' + e.target.name + " li").attr("value"));
             if(isNaN(sum))
                 sum = 0;
            if ($(this).is(':checked')){    
                    sum += price;          
                }
                else{
                    sum -= price;                   
                }
             $('#' + e.target.name + " li").remove();
            $('#' + e.target.name).append('<li value="' + sum + '">Cost: $'+sum+'</li>');
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfzrt3qt/4/

Comment: The problem is I'm comparing the ul name with the checkbox name so that the 2 sets of checkboxes do not add together I want them to add the values separately based on the product name

Comment: Oh ok so you appended and then parsed the int of the first list item after it had been added. That makes sense thank you very much.